# Regex - how to match boundary of a non-word character?

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I need to match the following:

```
-foo
foo-
```

But I don't want to match `foo-bar`.

I can't use `\b` as that doesn't match the boundary of the hyphen. My goal is to replace the hyphen with a space. Suggestions?

**UPDATE 1** (better example):

```
xxx yyy -foo foo- foo-bar zzz
```

I'm only interested in the strings `-foo` and `foo-`. The idea is to delete those hyphens. Hyphens are to hyphenate words. Meaning, there should be a word to its left and right. If it doesn't, then they hyphen shouldn't appear.

Comment: You're going to need to be a lot more specific about what you want to accept and what you want to reject. In addition, `\b` only matches a word boundary, so I can only assume you'd like to use it as part of some larger pattern. What's the larger pattern?

Comment: I was trying to see if I could use `\b` to match the beginning of the hyphen. No go. I really just need to match strings that start with a hyphen OR ends with a hyphen.

Comment: That's quite simple, then, and worry about word boundaries is just overcomplicating things. You should have said as much initially!

Comment: So you want to match `-foo` and `foo-`? Or just the hyphens in those substrings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with Negative lookahead and lookbehind:

```
$string = 'xxx yyy -removethis andthis- foo-bar zzz -andalsothis-';
$new_string = preg_replace('/(?<!\w)-(\w+)-(?!\w)|(?<!\w)-(\w+)|(\w+)-(?!\w)/', '$1$2$3', $string);
echo $new_string; // Output: xxx yyy removethis andthis foo-bar zzz andalsothis

/*
   (?<!\w) : Check if there is a \w behind, if there is a \w then don't match.
   (?!\w) : Check if there is a \w ahead, if there is a \w then don't match.
   \w : Any word character (letter, number, underscore)
*/
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/iN9uE0).

Answer (score 0):

My solution: `^-|-$| -|-`

```
Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «^-»
   Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
   Match the character “-” literally «-»
Or match regular expression number 2 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «-$»
   Match the character “-” literally «-»
   Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
Or match regular expression number 3 below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) « -»
   Match the characters “ -” literally « -»
Or match regular expression number 4 below (the entire match attempt fails if this one fails to match) «- »
   Match the characters “- ” literally «- »
```